# Calculation with Date in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

How can I add or subtract from a date in Google Earth Engine?
See my codes here-

```
var imagedate = ee.Date(collectionLT05_1991_1.get('system:time_start'));
var imaagedate1 = imagedate+1;
print(imagedate1);
```

I want the day after the "imagedate".
Is there any specific library for this ? or suggest me the appropriate codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your variable `imagedate` is of type `ee.Date`.  This means that the variable lives on the Earth Engine Server, not on your browser.

It takes a while to wrap one's head around it.  But any variable that is declared with the `ee.` prefix lives on the server and requires `ee` functions to do manipulations on them.  You can't use ordinary javascript on them.

The way to add a day to your date is to do it like this.

```
var imagedate1 = imagedate.advance(1,"day");
print(imagedate1);
```

The `.advance()` function is for dates in Earth Engine, allowing your to advance the number of units you choose.  (See the [ee.Date](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eedate) section in the docs)

Comment: great explanation!